# How to replay recorded FFT samples?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I record FFT ("*Fast Fourier Transform*") samples from audio like this:

```
 const no_samples = 100;

 const samples = [];
 for (let i = 0, l = no_samples; i < l; ++i) {
     samples.push({ sample: new Uint8Array(this.sampleSize), time:-1 });
 }
 var lambdaToRemove = null;

 let samplesDone = 0;
 let start = -1;
 let second = 0;

 this.scriptProcessor.addEventListener("audioprocess", lambdaToRemove =
 /**
  * @param {AudioProcessingEvent} event
  * */
     (event) => {
         // firefox provides data even before user allows acces to microphone
         if (!this.mediaAllocated) {
             console.log("Sample before media was allocated!");
             return;
         }

         // AudioAnalyser - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode
         this.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(samples[samplesDone].sample);
         ++samplesDone;

         if (samplesDone >= no_samples) {
             this.scriptProcessor.removeEventListener("audioprocess", lambdaToRemove);
             resolve(samples);
         }
 });
```

The relevant line is:

```
this.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(samples[samplesDone].sample);
```

This call populates an `Uint8Array` with FFT data. The length is pre-set and fixed.

So now I have an array with `Uint8Array`s representing the recorded audio. How can I feed the data back to some audio stream to play it in the browser?

I would like to record sound as FFT, modify it and then play it back.

I tried this:

```
/** @type {{time:number, sample:Uint8Array}[]} **/
const samples = this.getSamples();
this.oscilator = this.audioContext.createOscillator();
this.oscilator.connect(this.audioContext.destination);

let ctime = 0;
const ssize = samples[0].sample.length;
const imaginary = new Float32Array(ssize);
const half255 = 255 / 2;
this.oscilator.start();

for (let i = 0, l = samples.length; i < l; ++i) {
    const sample = samples[i];
    await sleep(sample.time - ctime);
    ctime = sample.time;
    const real = new Float32Array(ssize);
    // convert 0->255 to -1.0->1.0
    for (let is = 0, ls = real.length; is < ls; ++is) {
        real[is] = (sample.sample[is] / half255) / half255;
    }

    const wave = this.audioContext.createPeriodicWave(real, imaginary);
    this.oscilator.setPeriodicWave(wave);

}
this.isPlaying = false;
this.oscilator.stop();
```

But it just sounds like a buzzer. There must be a way to transition from one wave to another.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to resynthesize the audio using sine waves, as that's basically what the FFT decomposition is.

In particular, you'd be implementing a kind of a [vocoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocoder).

You can picture the array of FFT values at a particular point of time as the amplitudes of sine wave oscillators at that point in time, with `fft[0]` being a 0 hz oscillator and `fft[n - 1]` being an oscillator tuned to half of your original sampling rate (Nyquist theorem).

The quality of the resynthesis will probably not be excellent, though; the larger the FFT array, the better frequency resolution you'll have (probably at the expense of temporal resolution).

Comment: How can I resynthesize it? I tried using the `OscillatorNode` and `PeriodicWave` but switching the wave creates loud buzzing sound, therefor no audio can be heard. I have 48samples/sec, not perfect but should be comprehensible.

Comment: OscillatorNodes in sine mode should work fine. The OscillatorNodes need to be rather quiet each though, since there are lots of them.